# How to change font colour in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

I have a problem with netbeans. Somehow the font color changed to white on a white background. I am stuck and can't find anything.

I can only check by clicking on the option as the selection becomes blue and white can be seen on it.

Check the image

[image: mage]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> Options then to Fonts and Colors tab.

[a] For the javadoc parameters, select Java Language from the dropdown menu. It is the Javadoc Tag.

[b] For the selection, Highlighting tab and Selected Text Option.

Comment: Please, check out the screenshot I attached. I didn't mean the selected text. I meant the selected option.